# Where is the OpenSuSE server ISO for download?

Tags: system-installation, opensuse, webserver, iso, download

Which [download](https://download.opensuse.org/distribution/openSUSE-current/iso/) is the "server" version for OpenSuSE?

```
Index of download.opensuse.org/distribution/openSUSE-current/iso/
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Metadata
[DIR]   Parent Directory        -    
[ ] openSUSE-Leap-42.3-DVD-x86_64.iso   24-Jul-2017 17:08   4.3G    Details
[ ] openSUSE-Leap-42.3-DVD-x86_64.iso.sha256    24-Jul-2017 17:08   630     Details
[ ] openSUSE-Leap-42.3-DVD-x86_64.iso.torrent   25-Jul-2017 14:39   44K     Details
[ ] openSUSE-Leap-42.3-DVD.iso.torrent  25-Jul-2017 14:39   44K     Details
[ ] openSUSE-Leap-42.3-NET-x86_64.iso   24-Jul-2017 17:08   108M    Details
[ ] openSUSE-Leap-42.3-NET-x86_64.iso.sha256    24-Jul-2017 17:08   630     Details
```

I also went to the main SuSE site, but it everything was trial software.

Comment: there's no specialized medium for different desktops or flavours. Simply one install medium for all flavours and you can select what you want during installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the `openSUSE-Leap-42.3-DVD-x86_64.iso`

When you will start the installation  process, it will ask you for `Desktop Selection`, there you can choose `Minimal Server Selection (Text Mode)`

[image]

**Edit**

There is also [SUSE enterprise Linux Server](https://www.suse.com/products/server/download/), it can be used to install the OS headlessly but it isn't offered freely. They give a 30-day. You can try it on `kvm`.

Comment: will this work installing through kvm on ubuntu?  virtualized OpenSuSE server is what I want.  (didn't think through install process.)

Comment: I have updated the answer